# Translations: Move Column values into new rows

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have an excel file of content translations with content keys, their language, and the content.
Each content key has translated content in 20-25 languages

I want to update this report so that each language option has one column, and each content key has one row, with each translation for that particular key in the same row.

So, from this:

| Content Key | Language | Content |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Key 1 | en-US | Goodbye |
| Key 1 | de-DE | Auf Wiedersehen |

to this:

| Content Key | en-US | de-DE |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Key 1 | Goodbye | Auf Wiedersehen |

The only way I've been able to do this successfully so far is to export each language individually and use a Vlookup to match the translated content to the matching key in my master list.

Answer (score 3):

You can use this formula:

```
=LET(data,A2:C5,
k,UNIQUE(INDEX(data,,1)),
l,TOROW(UNIQUE((INDEX(data,,2)))),
m,MAKEARRAY(ROWS(k),COLUMNS(l),
        LAMBDA(r,c,FILTER(INDEX(data,,3),(INDEX(data,,1)=INDEX(k,r))*(INDEX(data,,2)=INDEX(l,,c)),""))),
HSTACK(VSTACK("",k),VSTACK(l,m)))
```

[image]

Comment: This is a good formula-driven solution if the user is on 365.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the input data follow the same pattern, i.e. all keys are grouped and all the translations are within the same order for each key (if not, then define `in` as follows: `SORT(A2:C7,{1,2},{1,1})` for example). Also, no Excel version constraints as per the tags listed in the question:

You can try the following:

```
=LET(in,A2:C7, uxKey,UNIQUE(TAKE(in,,1)), lang,UNIQUE(INDEX(in,,2)),
 cont,WRAPROWS(TAKE(in,,-1),ROWS(lang)), h,HSTACK("Content Key", TOROW(lang)),
 VSTACK(h, HSTACK(uxKey,cont)))
```

Here is the output:
[image: output]

The key here is to use `WRAPROWS` for the translations, wrapping by the number of unique languages. The rest is just to accommodate the result to the expected output.

Comment: I like the `WRAPROWS` idea - but it only works if per key there are the same languages in the same sort order. Your formula won't work with my sample data ... Sample data from question don't clarify that, it only says that each key is translated to 20 to 25 languages ...

Comment: yes, that is true @Ike I was not able to identify the pattern with the sample data, so that is why I put the assumptions in the preamble of my answer. I guess it is reasonable, that you would like to have all the keys translated to all the languages, if the order changes, then it can be sorted first. That is why I shared the answer (it is also a simple approach), I think it is a reasonable assumption, the OP can clarify it. Thanks for your feedback.

Answer (score 1):

*There are many ways to work on this, but in terms of **flexibility**, I would use `POWER QUERY` here which can **effortlessly** do the automation thus saving **time and effort** not just that it is scalable & one time approach no need to extend ranges can work with large range of datasets. `Power Query`, available in `Windows Excel 2010+` and `Excel 365 (Windows or Mac)`*. Watch the demonstration for reference. Takes less then **a minute** to perform the task.

---

[image]

---

To use Power Query follow the steps:

- First convert the source ranges into a table and name it accordingly, for this example I have named it as `Langtbl`

---

- Next, open a blank query from <kbd>Data</kbd> Tab --> <kbd>Get & Transform Data</kbd> --> <kbd>Get Data</kbd> --> <kbd>From Other Sources</kbd> --> <kbd>Blank Query</kbd>

---

- The above lets the <kbd>Power Query</kbd> window opens, now from <kbd>Home</kbd> Tab --> <kbd>Advanced Editor</kbd> --> And paste the following <kbd>M-Code</kbd> by removing whatever you see, and press <kbd>Done</kbd>

---

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Langtbl"]}[Content],
    #"Pivoted Column" = Table.Pivot(Source, List.Distinct(Source[Language]), "Language", "Content")
in
    #"Pivoted Column"
```

---

[image]

---

- Lastly, to import it back to <kbd>Excel</kbd> --> Click on <kbd>Close & Load</kbd> or <kbd>Close & Load To</kbd> --> The first one which clicked shall create a <kbd>New Sheet</kbd> with the required output while the latter will prompt a window asking you where to place the result.

---

*Perhaps one could use `PIVOTBY()` as well but while writing this formula, one needs to have enabled the `Beta` Channel in `MS365`.*

[image]

---

```
=LET(
     _Data, PIVOTBY(A2:A9,B2:B9,C2:C9,ARRAYTOTEXT,,0,,0,-1),
     SORTBY(_Data,XLOOKUP(TAKE(_Data,1),{"","en-US"},{1,2},3),1))
```

---

Answer (score 0):

Highlight your table and under the 'Data' tab of the ribbon, select 'From Table/Range'. Then when the power query windows opens, don't worry it's very straightforward.

In the power query window ribbon, under 'Transform', select your last 2 columns and choose 'Pivot column', make sure the value is set to 'Content' and under advanced options select "Don't Aggregate". And this will lay the information exactly as you asked. Now under the "Home" tab, hit 'Close & Load' and you will see it produces the table. As you add data to the original table, refreshing this new table will continue to pivot the results how you described without needing to rebound the range.